# How to implement an atomic increment of a pointer to an integer using std::atomic?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

While porting some Windows C++ code to iOS, I need to provide an implementation of Win32's `long InterlockedIncrement(long *p)` call. This is easy enough using the functions defined in `<libkern/OSAtomic.h>`.

However, I am wondering whether it's possible to write it in a OS-agnostic way using just the C++11 facility, mainly `<atomic>`. I came up with this, which I am not sure accomplishes what I want:

```
inline long InterlockedIncrement(long* p)
{
    std::atomic<long&> atomicP(*p);
    return ++atomicP;
}
```

Does this work? Is that good enough? The two lines are not atomic, but the increment should be atomic, which is the key here.

All the examples of use for `<atomic>` that I found are different, where a `std::atomic<T>` is defined and used directly. Here I want to use an existing long variable that the callers passes to me by address. I couldn't find such an example.

Edit: Clang 3.2 (in Xcode 4.x) fails to compile `++atomicP` with the error "cannot increment value of type `std::atomic<long&>`" (nor `atomicP += 1` either).

What would be the correct way?

Edit again: a pointer implementation compiles...

```
inline long InterlockedIncrement(long* p)
{
    std::atomic<long*> atomicP(p);
    return ++(*atomicP);
}
```

But I'm afraid this doesn't work, since I don't increment an atomic type, but the value pointed by the pointer, which is not atomic.

Comment: I don't think you can have an `atomic<T&>`. And the pointer version is wrong (the stored pointer itself will be atomic, not the pointed-to value).

Comment: No, this won't work at all without implementation-specific things.

Comment: Maybe it's time to convert it to `std::atomic<int>` for the port? Considering that `long` has different sizes on Windows and OSX, you will probably have to do something OS specific anyway.

Comment: Are you sure? iOS has 4-byte ints and longs, and I thought Win32 too. Then, what do you mean? Suppose I can use ints everywhere here. How would that help me?

Comment: If you could use `std::atomic<int>` or `std::atomic<long>` you could use `atomic_fetch_add` operation to increment variables. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example implementation is constructing a new atomic from a pointer each time. This is not the intended use of std::atomic and I do not believe it works how you would like.

To my knowledge, the only way to do what you are looking to do (remove dependence on InterlockedIncrement in a platform independent way) is to replace all declarations for variables that you currently are calling Win32 "interlock" calls on with std::atomic versions of them. Then, you can remove the interlocked calls and use regular value semantics to modify the variable atomically. This is more readable (and more maintainable in the future), anyway.

I understand you wish to leave existing (well tested) code in place but I don't think you can in your case.

Comment: I was afraid of that. You summarised my situation correctly. Thanks for your assessment.

Answer (score 5):

**`__atomic_add_fetch` GCC extension**

In GCC 4.8, the C++ standard library implements `std::atomic::operator++` with the GCC built-in `__atomic_add_fetch`, so you could write:

```
inline long InterlockedIncrement(long* p)
{
    return __atomic_add_fetch(p, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}
```

I'm not sure for clang, but there seem to be some options like `__c11_atomic_fetch_add` http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html

As others mentioned, the argument `p` itself would have to be `std::atomic` for you to use only the standard library methods: converting the pointer into atomic does not help because the atomic pointer only acts on the pointer, not on what it points to.

Comment: Also note that the GCC built-in may or may not be available in clang.

Comment: @caps Under what conditions are they available? clang version, build-options, etc.

Comment: In my case it with Clang 3.7.0 on a CentOS 6 using `std=c++14` and using gcc's standard library implementation. That last is probably the key bit, since I imagine that is where it is pulling the `__atomic_add_fetch` from. My IDE (which is running on OSX) does not recognize the function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use an `atomic_fetch_add` operation. Take a look at the example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_fetch_add).

Comment: That needs an existing `std::atomic` variable.

Comment: Since he is porting the code from Windows he could take into account this and introduce atomic variables (long -> std::atomic<long>)

Comment: Of course he could, but that isn't the question he is asking. The question specifically says he want to be passed `long*` instead of `std::atomic<long>`.

Comment: Hm, sorry I missed this part: _Here I want to use an existing long variable that the callers passes to me by address_...

Answer (score 1):

While this question is about C++11, it's worth providing a C++20 solution for future readers. There is now [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) which is a standard way of accomplishing this goal.

```cpp
#include <atomic>

// note: this should ideally take a reference instead of a pointer for a cleaner API
inline long InterlockedIncrement(long& p)
{
    // (1) using operator overloads with std::memory_order::seq_cst
    return ++std::atomic_ref(p);

    // (2) using an explicit memory order
    // note: ++x can be implemented as (x++ + 1)
    return std::atomic_ref(p).fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed) + 1;
}
```